# How to get logged in user id in Django

Tags: python, django

I am very new in Python and Django. A am trying to make app but I have an issue.
Can anyone help me, please xD
I can't get id of authenticated user...
I tried it in this way, and many other ways...

**views.py**

```
class CreateProfile(CreateView):
    template_name = 'layout/add_photo.html'
    model = Profile
    fields = ['image', 'user']
```

**html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="username"> #Here has to be field filled in with logged in user
    <input type="file" name="image"> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save Changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And when I'm starting app, and want to change/add picture, I can do it for anyone from my database, not only for logged in user.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFaYf.png)

Thanks for patience and help!

Comment: you can get the user id with:  'request.user.id'

Comment: The line `user = Profile.user` makes no sense and you should remove it.

Comment: Thank You! Ou, that was mistake. I forgot to delete this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Django ClassBasedViews you can get your user's id as `self.request.user.id` and in your template as `{{ user.id }}`

To check if someone is authenticated you can use `self.request.user.is_authenticated()` and in your template `{% if user.is_authenticated %} .. {% endif %}`

```
class CreateProfile(CreateView):
    template_name = 'layout/add_photo.html'
    model = Profile
    fields = ['image', 'user']

    # For example, if you want to return to a certain user
    # profile (which requires url adjustments to take a Primary Key)
    def get_success_url(self):
        user_id = self.request.user.id # Get user_id from request
        return reverse_lazy('git_project:user_profile', kwargs={'id': user_id})
```

Comment: Thank You! I will try something like this.

Comment: No xD. I can't make function in this CreateProfile class to return me logged in user ID. I don't know what is the problem. I 'll keep trying :)

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example. If you would like to have an example within your code, please where me a method where you want to use the `self.request.user`

Comment: I want to insert a picture for logged in user. So when i open the form, I have to browse picture, and it worked great, but the first field is username, and that field has to be filled in with logged in user. In my app, I have to select user from database, and thats not good. I want that be field automatically filled in with logged in username and when I click "Save Changes", the data will be saved in database. I have updated my Question. Thank You for all Your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: If the current issue is solved, please mark the current issue as resolved by accepting the satisfying answer. The new issue is not related to this current question, and should not be added into another question. Please try to figure your new issue out, and if you're not able to fix it, please create a new question with the required details.

Comment: I did it! It works perfect now. Thanks for Your help! :)